# Boot up problems after install of pcie card

Tags: windows-7, boot, 64-bit, pci-express

I have purchased a hp ethernet 1gb 2-port 33t network adaptor. 
I wanted to install it into a HP Elite desk 800 Gl Tower(320 W PSU)
I installed it but then the PC would not boot up. It gives 5 beeps which is the code for memory error.

I took out the card put it in a different HP computer which booted up fine.

The PC has no graphics cards, 1 HDD, mouse, keyboard, 1 extra dual serial port card.
In the bios the slots are all active, and it is in legacy mode.

Anyone got an ideas what is wrong?`

Comment: Check the RAM?  If 5 beeps is a memory error, I would look at that.

Comment: It's incredibly unlikely to have been an issue with modern power supplies and hardware, but did you happen to ground yourself when installing the card protecting from ESD?

Comment: Does it boot when you remove the network adapter? I'm with @jatuttle0, it's easy to inadvertently damage hardware if not properly grounded.

Comment: Assuming the other computer you tested the PCI card in accepts the same RAM, try testing each stick by itself in the other computer. Do a bunch of single-change tests and see what fails vs what boots.

Comment: I removed the card and it boots fine. I also put the card in to a different pc where it booted fine. Idid ground my self :). I get a new card tomorrow so i will try that and report.

Comment: I put in the new nic and it booted straight away.. so myproblem is solved if not the mystery